# How to get sending address of a deposit using coinbase api

Tags: coinbase.com

I am trying to integrate the Coinbase API to my website. I need to communicate with Coinbase's wallets (bitcoin, bitcoin cash etc.) programmatically. Currently I can create different wallet addresses using the API and also I get notified when buy or sell transactions happen.

But I need to know is it possible to get incoming address when a deposit occur to one of my address from outside or another account of Coinbase.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible because to get the "sending address" because such things do not exist in Bitcoin. There is not "send from" address in Bitcoin transactions. Furthermore many transactions will "send from" multiple addresses (i.e. they have multiple inputs).